# Extracting Nested POJO Object with Rest-Assured

Tags: kotlin, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I'm writing some tests using rest-assured and its Kotlin extensions to test some simple Spring MVC endpoints. I'm trying to understand how to extract values.

One endpoint returns a `BookDetailsView` POJO, the other returns a `Page<BookDetailsView>` (where `Page` is an interface provided by Spring for doing paging).

`BookDetailsView` is a really simple Kotlin data class with a single field:

```
data class BookDetailsView(val id: UUID)
```

For the single object endpoint, I have:

```
    @Test
    fun `single object`() {
        val details = BookDetailsView(UUID.randomUUID())

        whenever(bookDetailsService.getBookDetails(details.id)).thenReturn(details)
        val result: BookDetailsView = Given {
            mockMvc(mockMvc)
        } When {
            get("/book_details/${details.id}")
        } Then {
            statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        } Extract {
            `as`(BookDetailsView::class.java)
        }
        assertEquals(details.id, result.id)
    }
```

This works as expected, but trying to apply the same technique for the `Page<BookDetailsView>` runs afoul of all sorts of parsing challenges since Page is an interface, and even trying to use `PageImpl` isn't entirely straightforward. In the end, I don't even really care about the `Page` object, I just care about the nested list of POJOs inside it.

I've tried various permutations like the code below to just grab the bit I care about:

```
    @Test
    fun `extract nested`() {
        val page = PageImpl(listOf(
            BookDetailsView(UUID.randomUUID())
        ))
        whenever(bookDetailsService.getBookDetailsPaged(any())).thenReturn(page)

        val response = Given {
            mockMvc(mockMvc)
        } When {
            get("/book_details")
        } Then {
            statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            body("content.size()", `is`(1))
            body("content[0].id", equalTo(page.first().id.toString()))
        } Extract {
            path<List<BookDetailsView>>("content")
        }
        println(response[0].javaClass)
    }
```

The final `println` spits out `class java.util.LinkedHashMap`. If instead I try to actually use the object, I get `class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class BookDetailsView`. There are lots of questions and answers related to this, and I understand it's ultimately an issue of the underlying JSON parser not knowing what to do, but I'm not clear on:

1. Why does the "simple" case parse without issue?
2. Shouldn't the type param passed to the `path()` function tell it what type to use?
3. What needs configuring to make the second case work, OR
4. Is there some other approach for grabbing a nested object that would make more sense?

Digging a bit into the code, it appears that the two cases may actually be using different json parsers/configurations (the former seems to stick to rest-assured JSON parsing, while the latter ends up in JsonPath's?)

Comment: I ultimately realized that exposing `Page<BookDetailsView>` directly was a bad idea for other reasons and by changing it to something else the whole problem went away. I'll leave the question up in case it's relevant to someone else, though.

Comment: Can you please unaccept the answer? It seems it did not work for you and it does not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know kotlin but here is the thing:

- `path()` doesn't know the Element in your List, so it'll be `LinkedHashMap` by default instead of `BookDetailsView.class`
- to overcome it, you can provide TypeReference for this.

java example

```
List<BookDetailsView> response = ....then()
                .extract().jsonPath()
                .getObject("content", new TypeRef<List<BookDetailsView>>() {});
```

kotlin example

```
@Test
fun `extract nested`() {
    var response = RestAssured.given().get("http://localhost:8000/req1")
            .then()
            .extract()
            .jsonPath()
            .getObject("content", object : TypeRef<List<BookDetailsView?>?>() {});

    println(response)
    //[{id=1}, {id=2}]
}
```

Comment: In a lot of Kotlin libs/wrappers, the type info in `path<List<BookDetailsView>>("content")` would get reified and used to figure out the type, but it looks like that doesn't happen in this call chain. I think the equivalent Kotlin for your java would be
`body().jsonPath().getObject("content[0]", object : TypeRef<BookDetailsView>() {})` but now I'm getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Class cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType` (I get the same general error whether trying to grab the whole collection, or just a specific item in it).

Comment: @AwesomeTown I've tested with kotin and it worked like a charm.

Comment: It does NOT work. class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to XXX